# What is the difference when programming microcontroller 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit?

Tags: microcontroller

People always want an engineer who can program/have experience in both 8, 16 and 32 bit controllers. I still cannot figure out is there a huge difference when we program 8, 16, 32 bit microcontroller? Or it's just different in terms of declaring variables ...

Comment: Is there a huge difference between driving a gearless moped and a 20 tonne grab truck? The techniques are very different, as are the facilities available. One obvious difference in your example is that the 8-bit processor cannot perform 16 or 32-bit arithmetic simply. I say that because you have not mentioned any high level language.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Weather Vane's comment.  Is there a difference driving a wee bitty compact car, a pickup truck, a moving van and a semi truck (tractor-trailer)?  Well, in a lot of respects they are the same, gas, brakes, steering wheel, seat, door, window, radio, headlights, all that stuff, you brake and gas and steer.  Could you move your house with a smart car?  Well not everything, although you could maybe get a small trailer for the bed and couch, but you could move a box or two at a time and make a ton of trips, the pickup fewer trips, the semi maybe one trip depends on how much stuff you have.

If you are programming high level like C then initially it will feel the same, gas, brake, steer.  But it is like taking many trips to move your stuff or a few or one.  You can in general do 64 bit math with an 8 bit processor, a 16 and we know a 32 because we do that all the time and naturally a 64 bit.   It just takes more trips, you have to break the math down into parts and do the parts one at a time.   And naturally like using your fiat to move the stuff in your apartment it takes a lot more time than using a truck.

Just saw someone here using floating point on a Microchip PIC, see that all too often (float on a microcontroller), if the compiler has a library for it it allows folks to try it, but they very quickly run out of flash and/or ram and their performance is dreadful.

So in some respects it is about knowing that variables are not the same sizes you are used to on windows or linux, that things take longer, you have a lot fewer resources, debugging is or can be quite a bit different, its like getting out of your VW bug which is the only car you have ever driven then getting in a pickup truck or moving van, and clipping the curbs or parked cars every time you turn, not being able to stop at the lights, etc.  Eventually you get used to it.  Unlike the moving truck, you usually cant hurt the bits in the processor when you screw up, you can let smoke out with software and brick a system sure, but hopefully more often the program doesnt build or doesnt run or runs really slow and you dont have to go to jail each time for running over a pedestrian standing on the corner.

In this day and age (and actually for a long time but very trivial now) you can find all kinds of simulators/emulators that you can try to get a feel for these platforms.  The performance thing may be incorrect, but if you only have 1024 bytes of ram and a few Kbytes of flash, you are going to feel that right away, and wonder why only a few lines of high level code consume so many instructions.  Understanding things like maybe on that 8 bit mcu I should use mostly 8 bit variables so I dont burn so much code (unless the compiler figures it out, still wasteful), likewise on the 16 use mostly 16 bit and the 32 mostly 32 bit. (trying to "conserve" memory on a larger platform can actually cost you more cycles having to sign extend or clip every operation if it doesnt have native instructions for that or adding extra instructions to do that sign extension or clipping).